# Quarkus - Responding with status based on kafka write ack and nack

Tags: apache-kafka, quarkus, smallrye, smallrye-reactive-messaging

I have an endpoint which pushes data to kafka. Now, I want to respond to the call with the appropiriate status code 2xx or 5xx in case of kafka write success or failure respectively. The code snippet is

```
@Path("/prices")
public class PriceResource {

    @Inject @Channel("price-create") Emitter<Double> priceEmitter;

    @POST
    @Consumes(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
    public void addPrice(Double price) {
        priceEmitter.send(Message.of(price)
            .withAck(() -> {
                // Called when the message is acked
                return CompletableFuture.completedFuture(null);
            })
            .withNack(throwable -> {
                // Called when the message is nacked
                return CompletableFuture.completedFuture(null);
            }));
         // return appropriate response
          return Response
    }
}
```

Now the issue is that the endpoint is responding with the status code before ack or nack callback is executed.
Also tried the `sendAndAwait` method of `MutinyEmitter` but that method returns void. So there is no way to know if the message is acked or nacked.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The best way here is to chain async operations, like this:

```
@POST
@Consumes(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
public Uni<Response> addPrice(Double price) {
    return Uni.createFrom().completionStage(priceEmitter.send(price))
            .onItem().transform(ignored -> Response.ok().entity("foo").build())
            .onFailure().recoverWithItem(Response.serverError().build());
}
```

If you want to work with sync code (I do not recommend):

```
@Blocking
@POST
@Consumes(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
public Response addPrice(Double price) {
    try {
        Uni.createFrom().completionStage(priceEmitter.send(price))
                .await().indefinitely();

        return Response.ok().entity("foo").build();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        return Response.serverError().build();
    }
}
```

The .await().indefinitely() will throw an exception in case of the Uni emitting a failure.

You also have the option to work directly with the CompletionStage returned by the emitter without converting it to a Uni, but remember  Quarkus chose Mutiny as its default reactive framework.

Comment: @Vincius thanks. One question though. What if instead returning Uni<Response>, I just want to return a String. How do I get the value on fail/success from Uni.

Comment: You can use Uni#await and annotate the method with @Blocking to get a sync response but I do not recommend this since Emitter#send is async in nature. You can easily return the String using Response.ok().entity(...).